# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 32, 3, 32)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a 3d cnn network on Cifar 10 dataset, but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kI3DV2s.py", line 286, in <module>
    callbacks=[])
  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 150, in fit_generator
    val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)
  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 135, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 32, 3, 32)
```

I think the issue has to do with the input shape and the x_train dimensions.

The relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
nb_classes = 10

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

# reorder dimensions for tensorflow
x_train = np.transpose(x_train.astype('float32') / 255., (0, 2, 3, 1))
x_test = np.transpose(x_test.astype('float32') / 255., (0, 2, 3, 1))
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)


img_rows, img_cols, img_rc = 32, 32, 32
img_channels = 3


inputs = Input(shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_rc, img_channels))

# 3d cnn model
...
...
...

model = Model(input=inputs, output=predictions)

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 128
nb_epoch = 10
data_augmentation = True

# Model saving callback
#checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='stochastic_depth_cifar10.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

if not data_augmentation:
    print('Not using data augmentation.')
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                        batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1,
                        validation_data=(x_test, y_test), shuffle=True,
                        callbacks=[])
else:
    print('Using real-time data augmentation.')

    # realtime data augmentation
    datagen_train = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,
        samplewise_center=False,
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,
        zca_whitening=False,
        rotation_range=0,
        width_shift_range=0.125,
        height_shift_range=0.125,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=False)
    datagen_train.fit(x_train)

    # fit the model on the batches generated by datagen.flow()
    history = model.fit_generator(datagen_train.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True),
                                  samples_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0], 
                                  nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1,
                                  validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                                  callbacks=[])
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how can I get the dimensions right. Thank you.

Note:

```
x_train shape: (50000, 32, 3, 32) 
50000 train samples 
10000 test samples
```

```
Window 10
Python 3.7.6
Tensorflow-gpu==1.14
Keras==2.3.1
```

Comment: try `inputs = Input(shape=(None,img_rows, img_cols, img_rc, img_channels))`, the model require 5 dimension the first one must be a batch size

Comment: Thanks for replying. When I do that I get this error ```ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv3d_1: expected ndim=5, found ndim=6```.

Comment: you don't need `None`, I written my sample code and it works `x = Input(shape=(32,32,32,3))
y = Conv3D(16, (1,1,1),activation='relu')(x)
model = Model(x, y)`, check the shape of your `x_train`

Comment: Is there a different way to define x_train, y_train for 3d cnn inputs?

Comment: could you post the sample from `x_train`

Comment: Do you mean this? ```x_train shape: (50000, 32, 3, 32)
50000 train samples
10000 test samples```

Comment: your `x_train` is only 3 dimension,the first `50000` is just data size,why your are using `Conv3D` on this data shape?

Comment: I am just testing the model with this, to see if it works fine. I intend to use it for video inputs eventually where there will be spatial and temporal features to account for. is there away I can reshape it

Comment: you can't use`Conv3D` with 3 dimension input, but you want to test you can use a radomly generated data to fit the shape of your input using `x=tf.random.normal([10,32,32,32,3], 0, 1, tf.float32) `,first `10` is your batch size and the others your input dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reshape it using the following code and testing it on 3d mnst dataset instead.

```
xtrain = np.ndarray((x_train.shape[0], 4096, 3))
xtest = np.ndarray((x_test.shape[0], 4096, 3))

## iterate in train and test, add the rgb dimension 
def add_rgb_dimension(array):
    scaler_map = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="Oranges")
    array = scaler_map.to_rgba(array)[:, : -1]
    return array
for i in range(x_train.shape[0]):
    xtrain[i] = add_rgb_dimention(x_train[i])
for i in range(x_test.shape[0]):
    xtest[i] = add_rgb_dimention(x_test[i])

xtrain = xtrain.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 16, 16, 16, 3)
xtest = xtest.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 16, 16, 16, 3)

## convert target variable into one-hot
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

y_train.shape
```